# Confusion regarding Quadratic equations and RHS = 0

Tags: logic, quadratics

Recently, I am becoming confused with how it is said that in a quadratic equation you **MUST** make the RHS $ = 0$. But I am stumbling across many equations where it is calculated (The following is for integer solutions) as e.g. $$2^{2x}-3^{2y} = 55$$ 
$$(2^x-3^y)(2^x+3^y)=55$$
so $$2^x-3^y = 5$$ or $$2^x-3^y = 11$$
Why is this possible? Isn't this wrong? How could you have a theorem that says $a\cdot b = c\cdot d$ so $a=c$ or $a=d$? What I am understanding is that you can also do this: $$(x+4)(x-2) = 10$$
so $$(x+4)(x-2) = 5\cdot 2$$
so $(x+4) = 5$ OR $(x-2)=2$, But this is not correct! So how is it allowed that we can do this for the first equation that I mentioned? And never mind the fact that if you took the 55 over in the first equation you would not be able to simplify it, I simply want an explanation to the arithmetic and logic taking place. Any help and explanations will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you only using integer numbers. And even then I think you've got the wrong idea about the ab=cd case. $4\cdot9=12\cdot3$ where the numbers 4, 9, 12 and 3 are all different from one another...

Comment: But why? Why is it that $2^x-3^y$ and $2^x+3^y$ have to be integers?

Comment: If the domain is not integers but reals, you will have an infinite number of  solutions. If the domain is integers you have a finite number of solutions namely `5*11`, `-1*-55`,`-5*-11` and `1*55`. There are no other integers that you can multiply which will give you 55.

Comment: this means that $2^x - 3^y$ and $2^x + 3^y$ can be any of `{-11, -5, -1, 1, 5, 11}` as long as their product = 55.

Comment: But I don't think you understand my query. I mean look at the second equation and explain why I am not allowed to do what I did in the first equation, I am not interested in the solutions.

Comment: If $x,y$ are reals, $2^x-3^y$ and $2^x+3^y$ don't have to be integers. But if $x,y$ are integers, $2^x-3^y$ and $2^x+3^y$ will be integers (they are power and sum of integers, which are integers). It depends on the domain.

Comment: In the second problem, you probably meant $x+4=5$ or $x+4=2$. What you wrote there is redundant, because if $x+4=5$, automatically you have $x-2=2$. So there is no point saying "$x+4=5$ or $x-2=2$". 
If $x,y$ are integers, then $(x+4)(x-2)$ is a factorization of some another integer. You know that this integer is $10$, which in turn can be factored as $2\cdot5$, which is a factorization in primes. The Fundamental theorem of arithmetic ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) ensures that this factorization is unique. Therefore $(x+4)(x-2)$ must be this factorization.

Comment: @user108104 I do understand your query, I was just trying to answer your question `why is it that 2^x - 3^y and 2^x + 3^y have to be integers?`. To your actual question, there is a huge difference between the two things you are comparing. One is a quadratic equation with a single variable,the other is an exponential equation with 2 different variables. They cannot be solved the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I originally posted this as a comment because MSE was, mysteriously, not allowing me to post answers. That has been resolved so I am posting it here now and have deleted the comments.)  The solution you present as one you are "stumbling across" is incorrect, for exactly the reasons you identify -- *unless* there is some context that specifies, for example, that the values of $x$ and $y$ must be positive integers.

In that case, we can use the fact that since $2^x - 3^y$ and $2^x + 3^y$ are both integers, and 5 is a prime, since 5 divides the product of the two integers it must divide (at least) one of them; likewise since 11 is prime and divides the product, it must divide (at least) one of them; and since 55 has no other prime factors, neither $2^x-3^y$ nor $2^x+3^y$ contains any extra prime factors.  Also, we observe that neither of them can be equal to 1.  So the *only* way to have two positive integers multiply to be 55 is for one of them to be 5 and the other one to be 11.

In other words:  In a number theory context, if we are limiting ourselves to integer solutions to problems, then there are additional heuristics that apply.